# Why I can't amend one field by using the chosen record from tableview backed by NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, null, nsmanagedobject, nslog, uistoryboard

```
(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSError *error=nil;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"Segue");
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:selectedObject];
        objet = selectedObject;

        [self showQuizz:selectedObject];
        int num=1;
        [selectedObject   setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:num] forKey:@"fldId"];
        if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"fldId Not Saved");
            NSLog(@"Handle the error");
            NSLog(@"Unresolved Error %@, %@",error, [error userInfo]);
        }
}
```

1. The print of the last NSLog is:  Unresolved Error (null), (null)

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should add a !, you should be checking if the result of save is NO, not YES:

```
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"fldId Not Saved");
            NSLog(@"Handle the error");
            NSLog(@"Unresolved Error %@, %@",error, [error userInfo]);
        }
```

In other words the call to save is succeeding. You can see more examples of this [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/04_Adding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH106-SW1).